# Rotation Arc Length in 4D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

If I have a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and I rotate it within the $xy$-plane ($0<\alpha<\pi$) and $zw$-plane ($0<\beta<\pi$), how can I determine the length of the arc traced by the rotation of $(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)$? I figure it probably involves integrating across a parametrization of the arc, but I'm not sure how to parametrize it in this situation.

Update- 
I am going to try to calculate a line element for hyperspherical coordinates. Now the struggle is going to be determining what parametrizations coordinate with rotations through which orthogonal planes. The angles in the coordinate system, however, are defined differently than the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Any assistance or feed back would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're rotating in these planes sequentially?  Or simultaneously?\

Comment: I guess simultaneously.  4D rotations can be simple, double, or isoclinic. This is a double rotation which requires two independent angles and two completely orthogonal planes whose direct sum is \mathbb{R}^4 to be completely defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\vx}{\Vec{x}}\newcommand{\vz}{\Vec{z}}$The orbit of a vector
$$
(x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0}, w_{0}) = (\vx, \vz)
$$
under the set of rotations in the $(x, y)$- and $(z, w)$-planes in $\Reals^{4}$ is a (Riemannian) product of circles with respective radii
$$
\|\vx\| = \|(x_{0}, y_{0})\| = \sqrt{x_{0}^{2} + y_{0}^{2}},\qquad
\|\vz\| = \|(z_{0}, w_{0})\| = \sqrt{z_{0}^{2} + w_{0}^{2}},
$$
namely a flat torus obtained by identifying opposite edges of the rectangle
$$
\bigl[0, 2\pi \|\vx\|\bigr] \times \bigl[0, 2\pi \|\vz\|\bigr].
$$

Rotation by $\alpha$ in the $(x, y)$-plane moves $(\vx, \vz)$ a geodesic distance $\alpha \|\vx\|$; rotation by $\beta$ in the $(z, w)$-plane moves $(\vx, \vz)$ a geodesic distance $\beta \|\vz\|$. These displacements are perpendicular in the torus orbit, so their net geodesic distance is given by the Pythagorean theorem:
$$
\sqrt{\alpha^{2} \|\vx\|^{2} + \beta^{2} \|\vz\|^{2}}
  = \sqrt{\alpha^{2}(x_{0}^{2} + y_{0}^{2}) + \beta^{2}(z_{0}^{2} + w_{0}^{2})}.
$$

To confirm, note that the one-parameter subgroup
$$
\gamma(t) = \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x_{0}\cos(\alpha t) - y_{0}\sin(\alpha t) \\
    y_{0}\cos(\alpha t) + x_{0}\sin(\alpha t) \\
    z_{0}\cos(\beta t) - w_{0}\sin(\beta t) \\
    w_{0}\cos(\beta t) + z_{0}\sin(\beta t)
  \end{array}
  \right],\quad 0 \leq t \leq 1,
$$
carries $(\vx, \vz)$ to its image under the combined rotation, and
$$
\|\gamma'(t)\|
  = \sqrt{\alpha^{2}(x_{0}^{2} + y_{0}^{2}) + \beta^{2}(z_{0}^{2} + w_{0}^{2})}.
$$

Comment: How would you generalize to a point in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ space? What components of the explanation above change with $ n $ and which ones are consistent through any dimensión rotation?

Comment: If $P_{1}$, ..., $P_{k}$ are _mutually orthogonal_ $2$-planes in $\Reals^{n}$, and if a vector $\vx$ is orthogonally decomposed as $\vx_{0} + \vx_{1} + \dots + \vx_{k}$, with $\vx_{i} \in P_{i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, an entirely analogous argument shows that rotating $P_{i}$ through an angle $0 < \alpha_{i} < \pi$ moves $\vx$ by $\sqrt{\sum_{i} \alpha_{i}^{2} \|\vx_{i}\|^{2}}$.

Comment: Thank for all your help thus far. I have just two more "sub-questions". Do I need to integrate $||\gamma'(t)||$ across $t$ in order to obtain the arclength as I've seen in some texts on Riemannian manifolds? Do these rotations necessarily trace geodesic curves on an $n$-sphere or torus?

Comment: Yes, technically you need to integrate $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ from $0$ to $1$; since $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ is constant, however, its value is equal to the integral (i.e., to the arc length). The curves traced are geodesics in the torus, but are "usually" not geodesics in the unit sphere.